# How to force fragment cache on rails from cron schedule?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, cron

Is there any way I can trigger a page to be fragment cached without having someone to load the page the first time?

I am planning to use cron schedule, this is because my cron scheduler updates the database and that's when I want to force the fragment cache to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a primitive solution but you could always have cron fire off a curl request to the URL of your page(s).

Comment: I was thinking of this if there is no other way.

Comment: I'd probably go this route too, what's the reason for you wanting to do this?

Comment: I don't know. Probably thinking there's a way to do it without using curl request.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code in a background worker.   it instantiates the controller in your code which then will render the views as appropriate and populate the caches.

```
cache_controller = PageController.new
cache_controller.response = Hashie::Mash.new({"content_type"=>"text/js"})
cache_controller.request = Hashie::Mash.new({"action"=>"show", "negotiate_mime"=>"js", "content_type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "get?" => true})
cache_controller.params = {id: 1}
cache_controller.action_name = 'show'
cache_controller.show  # this is the method on controller you want to call.
```

In my case I was hitting a js.erb so some of that content may not be needed in your example.