# Request a page with cron to update cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I use http caching on Heroku:

```
def homepage
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=86340'
  ...
end
```

I also have added Heroku's free cron addon:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do
 if Time.now.hour == 0 # run at midnight
   # I want to request a page here
 end
end
```

Could you tell me what should I put inside this file in order to request a page?

A similar question has been asked at [How to force fragment cache on rails from cron schedule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907354/how-to-force-fragment-cache-on-rails-from-cron-schedule)
They don't provide an example in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do
 if Time.now.hour == 0 # run at midnight
   uri = URI.parse('http://my-app.heroku.com/page')
   Net::HTTP.get(uri)
 end
end
```

That should do it.